# A vanishing condition for cup products in Galois cohomology

Tags: quadratic-forms, galois-cohomology

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $\neq 2$. For a non-zero element $a \in k^*$, let us write $[a] \in H^1(k,\mathbb{Z}/2)$ for the Galois cohomology class corresponding to the quadratic extension $k(\sqrt{a})/k$. If $a,b \in k^*$ are non-zero elements then the class $[a] \cup [b] \in H^2(k,\mathbb{Z}/2)$ is trivial if and only if $b$ is a norm from $k(\sqrt{a})/k$. In particular, if $ab = -1$ then $b=-a$ is a norm from $k(\sqrt{a})/k$ and hence $[a] \cup [b] = 0$. I have a reason to believe the following generalization is true:

**Claim**: Let $a_1,...,a_n \in k^*$ be such that $\prod_i a_i = -1$. Then $[a_1] \cup [a_2] \cup ... \cup [a_n] = 0$.

Is this claim true?

One way to approach this problem is via quadratic forms. Let us denote by $\left<b_1,...,b_n\right>$ the isomorphism class of the quadratic form $\sum_i b_i x_i^2$. The Witt ring $W(k)$ of $k$ is the ring generated by isomorphism classes of non-degenerate quadratic forms over $k$, modulu the relation $\left<1,-1\right> \sim 0$ (more precisely, the addition in $W(k)$ is determined by the direct sum operation and multiplication by tensor product). Let $I \subseteq W(k)$ be the ideal generated by forms of even rank. A deep result in the theory of quadratic forms (closely related to Milnor's conjecture), is that there is a natural isomorphism of graded rings 
$$ \oplus_n I^n/I^{n+1} \stackrel{\cong}{\longrightarrow} H^*(k,\mathbb{Z}/2) .$$ 
In particular, the class of $\left<1,-a\right> \in I$ (mod $I^2$) is sent to the class $[a] \in H^1(k,\mathbb{Z}/2)$, and hence the class of $\left<1,-a_1\right> \otimes ... \otimes \left<1,-a_n\right>$ is sent to $[a_1] \cup ... \cup [a_n]$. A possible strategy is then to show that if $\prod_i a_i = -1$ then the quadratic form $\left<1,-a_1\right> \otimes ... \otimes \left<1,-a_n\right>$ (which has rank $2^n$) is trivial (in the sense that it is isomorphic to a direct sum of $2^n$ copies of $\left<1,-1\right>$).

Comment: Pernickety remark : you should add $n\geq 2$ in the claim.

Comment: And in fact, over $\mathbf R$, the quadratic form $<1,-a>^{\otimes s}$ is never hyperbolic ... for $a<0$, in particular for $a=-1$ and $s$ odd ...

Comment: Yes, over $\mathbb R$, one has $\prod_{i=1}^3-1=-1$ and $[-1]\cup[-1]\cup[-1]\ne 0$ in $H^3(\mathbb R,\mathbb Z/2)$.

Comment: Right. Thank you. So my claim is simply wrong. I guess I have some reassessing to do then.

Comment: On the other hand, over any field $k$ one has $[x_1]\cup [x_2]\cup\dotsb\cup [x_{2m-1}]\cup[-x_1\dotsb x_{2m-1}]=$ $[x_1]\cup\dotsb\cup [x_{2m-1}]\cup[-x_1\cdot -x_2\cdot\dotsc\cdot-x_{2m-1}]=$ $[x_1]\cup \dotsb\cup [x_{2m-1}]\cup[-x_1]+\dotsb+[x_1]\cup\dotsb\cup[x_{2m-1}]\cup[-x_{2m-1}]=$ $0+\dotsb+0=$ $0$.  So your assertion is true for $n$ even and false for $n$ odd.

Comment: And for the same reason, one has $[a_1]\cup\dotsb\cup[a_n]=0$ for any $a_i$ such that $\prod_ia_i=1$ when $n$ is odd.

Answer (score 2):

After realizing that the claim is wrong (thanks to the answers above), I managed to find a weaker statement, that turned out to be what I needed anyway. So just in case someone else happens to be interested in this question, here is the idea.

For each $l$, let $\mu_l$ denote the Galois module of $l$-roots of unity. In particular, let us use $\mu_2 = \{1,-1\}$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}/2$. For each $n$ we have an inclusion of Galois modules $\mu_l \longrightarrow \mathbb{G}_m$. Now indeed it is not true that if $\prod_i a_i = -1$ then $[a_i] \cup ... \cup [a_i] = 0$. However, it is true that in this case the image of $[a_1] \cup ... \cup [a_n]$ in $H^n(k,\mathbb{G}_m)$ is $0$ (which happens to be sufficient for my original application).

To see this, consider the short exact sequence of Galois modules
$$ 0 \longrightarrow \mu_2 \longrightarrow \mu_4 \longrightarrow \mu_2 \longrightarrow 0 .$$
We then obtain a long exact sequence in homology groups, and in particular a boundary map
$$ H^{n-1}(k,\mu_2) \longrightarrow H^n(k,\mu_2) .$$
Unwinding the definitions, one can check that this boundary map sends a class $\alpha \in H^{n-1}(k,\mu_2)$ to the class $\alpha \cup [-1] \in H^n(k,\mu_2)$. Now, as explained in the answer above, it is sufficient to consider the case where $n > 1$ is odd. Let $a_1,...,a_n$ be such that $\prod_i a_i = -1$. Then, again as explained above, we have
$$ [a_1] \cup ... \cup [a_n] = [a_1] \cup ... \cup [a_{n-1}] \cup [-1] $$
and so $[a_1] \cup ... \cup [a_n]$ is in the image of the boundary map $H^{n-1}(k,\mu_2) \longrightarrow H^n(k,\mu_2)$. It follows that the image of $[a_1] \cup ... \cup [a_n]$ in $H^n(k,\mu_4)$ is $0$, and hence the image in $H^n(k,\mathbb{G}_m)$ is $0$ as well.

Comment: It's a bit more complicated, actually.  The Bockstein operator (boundary map) $H^{n-1}(k,\mu_2)\to H^n(k,\mu_2)$ corresponding to the short exact sequence $0\to\mu_2\to\mu_4\to\mu_2\to0$ always differs from the boundary map corresponding to the short exact sequence $0\to\mathbb Z/2\to\mathbb Z/4\to\mathbb Z/2\to0$ by the operator of multiplication with $[-1]$.  However, which of them is which depends on whether $n$ is odd or even.

Comment: When $n$ is odd, the former boundary map (which you are interested in) is the multiplication with $[-1]$ and the latter one vanishes.  When $n$ is even, the former one vanishes and the latter one is the multiplication with $[-1]$.

Comment: It's not just "unwinding the definitions"; it is a specific homological property of the absolute Galois groups which can be thought of as a weak version of the Milnor conjecture (though I vaguely recall that it may have been proven several years earlier than the Milnor conjecture was).  So your argument does indeed seem to work, but for a reason a bit more complicated than you say.

Comment: Thanks! I admit I was a bit hasty. Do you maybe have a reference for this result I can look at?

Comment: Not at the moment, by I can explain the reason, which is very simple.  The assertion is that the Bockstein operator $H^{n-1}(k,\mu_p^{\otimes n-1})\to H^n(k,\mu_q^{\otimes n-1})$ is always zero, because any element in $H^{n-1}(k,\mu_p^{\otimes n-1})$ can be lifted to an element of $H^{n-1}(k,\mu_{pq}^{\otimes n-1})$ by the Milnor-Bloch-Kato (as indeed it can be lifted even to the MIlnor K-theory component $K^M_{n-1}(k)$).

Comment: Now $\mu_2^{\otimes n-1}$ is always $\mathbb Z/2$ and $\mu_4^{\otimes n-1}$ may be $\mu_4$ or $\mathbb Z/4$ depending on whether $n$ is even or odd.  The rest must be indeed an elementary computation from the definitions, just as you say.

Comment: The reference that I had in mind was: Merkurʹev, A. S. On the norm residue homomorphism for fields. Mathematics in St. Petersburg, 49–71, Amer. Math. Soc. Transl. Ser. 2, 174, 1996.  Apparenly, it actually says that the vanishing of the Bockstein homomorphism that I mentioned is as strong an assertion as the Milnor conjecture.

Comment: So much for "unwinding the definitions" :)

Comment: :-) The point is that the group $H^1(G,\mathbb Z/2)$ for a profinite group $G$ can be interpreted as the group of extension classes $0\to \mathbb Z/2 \to M\to\mathbb Z/2\to 0$ in the category of discrete $G$-modules over $\mathbb Z/2$, but not over $\mathbb Z$.  In the Galois cohomology situation, the extension corresponding to the class $[-1]$ is some short exact sequence of $\mathbb Z/2$-vector spaces $0\to \mathbb Z/2\to M\to \mathbb Z/2\to 0$ with a discrete action of $G_k$.

Comment: So this extension is neither $0\to\mathbb Z/2\to\mathbb Z/4\to\mathbb Z/2\to 0$, nor $0\to\mu_2\to\mu_4\to\mu_2\to0$, but, in fact, their difference in the group of extensions in the abelian category of discrete $G_k$-modules over $\mathbb Z$.  This difference is indeed a short exact sequence of $\mathbb Z/2$-vector spaces, as the $\mathbb Z/4$ and the $\mu_4$-sequences represent the same extension in the category of abelian groups (when you forget the action of $G_k$), so their difference must split as an exact sequence of abelian groups, hence its middle term is a $\mathbb Z/2$-vector space.

Comment: This proves that the difference between the two extensions with the middle terms $\mathbb Z/4$ and $\mu_4$ corresponds to a certain class in $H^1(k,\mathbb Z/2)$, and the difference between the two Bockstein operators is the multiplication with this cohomology class.  Computing this degree-one cohomology class as $[-1]$ is the "unwinding the definitions" part of the story.